# How to access shared_preferences KVP from previous non-Flutter version of app

Tags: flutter, dart

So I made an iOS app in Swift, and published it to the app store. In that app, I have saved some important KVPs in UserDefaults.standard. Typically, when updating the app, the KVPs would transfer over to the updated version without issue.

Now I'm remaking the app in Flutter/Dart. I want a smooth transition for existing users. Specifically, when users update from the Swift version to the Flutter version, the UserDefaults data should still be stored. However, when I tried testing this out (using Flutter's shared_preferences module to get existing keys), the keys appeared to be "gone".

The reason they're "gone" is that Flutter prefixes all keys with "flutter.". As such, when it saves key XX, it's actually saving flutter.XX, and when you try to retrieve key XX, you're actually retrieving flutter.XX. But in the Swift version of the app, I saved it as XX, not flutter.XX (obviously), so now Flutter "can't find it".

The functionality that enforces the prefix is spread across shared_preferences.dart and SharedPreferencesPlugin.m. I could technically modify these files to remove the prefix, but I'm not aware if there would be any negative side effects to doing so.

Any ideas on either how to access my old KVPs without entirely modifying the Shared Preferences plugin? And/or anyone know whether modifying the plugin to remove the prefix would cause any unintended side effects?